# Problema con un condicional en un addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html5, condiciones, eventos

Buen dia compas, ando practicando los eventos con js y pues queria realizar un codigo donde al darle click a una imagen se cambie a otra y viceversa con un condicional pero no me funciona, alguno sabe que tengo mal en mi codigo, muchas gracias.

```
/* HTML

<body>
   <h1>cmbiar imagen</h1>

   <img id="imagen" src="cell1.jpg" width="400px" alt="">


   <script src="scritp.js"></script>

</body> */


// codigo js

let imagen = document.getElementById('imagen')

function cambiarimagen() {

   let imageSRC = imagen.src

   if (imageSRC == 'cell1.jpg') {
      imageSRC = 'cell2.jpg'
   } else {
      imageSRC = 'cell1.jpg'
   }
}

imagen.addEventListener('click', cambiarimagen)


// De esta manera me funciono facilmente pero lo que busco es una manera de poder regresar a la primera imagen de nuevo.

let imagen = document.getElementById('imagen')

imagen.addEventListener('click', () => {
   imagen.src = 'cell2.jpg'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí están pasando dos cosas:

1. Estas asignando el valor de la imagen a una variable nueva que en si no representa a objeto de la imagen. Al asignarle el valor de x a y, y no cambiará el valor de x si esta muta.

   **La manera equivocada**:

   ```javascript
   let imageSRC = imagen.src
   ...
   imageSRC = 'bar'
   ```

   Esto no afectará a el atributo src del objeto del nodo.

   **La manera correcta**:

   ```javascript
   imagen.src = 'foo'
   ...
   imagen.src = 'bar'
   ```
2. El nombre de la imagen probablemente no es `cell1.jpg`. Cuando obtienes el src de una imagen esta es una url completa que incluye el protocolo, el host, el path, ect. (por ejemplo `http://playcode.io/new/cell2.jpg`). Para evaluar esta condición debes obtener primero el nombre del archivo de alguna manera, en este caso con un `split` y `pop`:

   ```javascript
   let imageSRC = imagen.src.split('/').pop(); // => 'cell1.jpg' || 'cell2.jpg'
   ```

   O evaluar utilizando la url de la vista mas el nombre del archivo:

   ```javascript
   let file1 = document.URL + '/cell1.jpg'
   ...
   if (imageSRC == file1)
   ```

Como ultimo esto no requiere tanta sintaxis, podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
function cambiarimagen() {
   let imageSRC = imagen.src.split('/').pop();
   if (imageSRC == 'cell1.jpg') imagen.src = 'cell2.jpg'
   else imagen.src = 'cell1.jpg'
}
```

o simplemente:

```javascript
function cambiarimagen() {
   imagen.src = imagen.src.split('/').pop() === 'cell1.jpg' ? 'cell2.jpg' : 'cell1.jpg'
}
```

**Enlaces de interes**:

- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split)
- [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop)
- [Operadores ternarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator)

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: disculpa, la parte del tema del URL y de donde obtengo la imagen es un poco confuso, pues en mi caso tengo las 2 imagenes en la misma carpeta con el index.html y el .js, en ese sentido porque usaria metodos de array como .pop y .split ?

Comment: Hola, split no es un metodo de array, es un metodo de string. Y como explico, si obtienes el source de una imagen, por ejemplo `console.log(imagen.src)` esto será una url, en realidad un strig pero con la url completa a tu imagen. Para obtener solo el nombre de la imagen debes primero tomar esta url y extraer el nombre del archivo de la misma de alguna manera. En este caso lo que se hizo fue convertir el string a un array dividiendo con `/` y luego obteniendo el ultimo item de este array con pop, que por logica es el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Ah ya entiendo porque el .split y el .pop, es porque tu crees que tengo el src mal y no, hay esta bien, simplemente es asi ( src="cell1.jpg" ) porque la imagen como te comente anteriormente, esta en la misma carpeta, no la estoy trayendo desde una url externa ni nada, yo se que si estuviera en otra carpeta, ejemplo seria asi  (src="imagenes/cell1.jpg") pero reitero, ese no es el problema.

Comment: Bro... no creo que está en otra carpeta, las url del navegador no tienen nada que ver con tu sistema. El browser transforma los path relativos en paths absolutos, ya sea en localhost o en ubicación de disco. Lo que quiero decir es que sin importar que tu asignes imagen.src = 'cell1.jpg' el navegador creara una url absoluta hacia tu archivo y asi te lo devolverá cada vez la obtengas, si haces console.log(imagen.src) te daras cuenta que ahora cambio a `path/to/cell1.jpg` siendo path/to/cellq.jpg la url o path hacia tu archivo.

Comment: oye amigo perdona, acabo de entender que en el editor de codigo, especificamente el codigo html lo puedo enlazar asi como te comente anteriormente, pero mirando con el dir($0) en chrome, el src me muestra esto, "http://127.0.0.1:5500/ajax2/cell2.jpg", por lo que ahora tu respuesta cobro totalmente todo el sentido y me quito un poco mas mi ignorancia con JS, por lo que mi ultima pregunta es como deberia usar ese enlace con el .split ? gracias.

Comment: jajaja que bueno, ese enlace lo usas tal cual lo ves en la respuesta `imagen.src.split('/').pop()`, un saludo .

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119267/discussion-between-alex-garzon-and-dy-crawford).

Answer (score 0):

aqui una solucion espero te sirva saludos

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imagen">
        <img src="https://d500.epimg.net/cincodias/imagenes/2018/11/13/lifestyle/1542113135_776401_1542116070_noticia_normal.jpg" alt="" class="image">
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let array = ["https://www.adslzone.net/app/uploads-adslzone.net/2019/04/borrar-fondo-imagen.jpg", "https://d500.epimg.net/cincodias/imagenes/2018/11/13/lifestyle/1542113135_776401_1542116070_noticia_normal.jpg"]
    let i = 0;
    let imagen = document.querySelector(".image");
    let l = imagen.src;
    let div = document.querySelector(".imagen").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        imagen.src = array[i];
        i++;
        if (i > array.length - 1)
            i = 0;
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una respuesta con explicación siempre será mejor recibida

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stack, te recomiendo que hagas lo que te comentan arriba, pero aun asi no puedo evitar notar que tu respuesta es un poco overkilled para un simple toggle hahaha cuando menos es interesante, un saludo.

Comment: Ahhh con que lo que quiero hacer se llama "Toggle" que es cambiar el estado de un elemento a otro y viceversa, precisamente era algo que iba a hacer despues con un barMenu, que bien ! simplifica mucho mejor mi cuestion, gracias. Respecto al aporte del usuario Cristian, totalmente de acuerdo, funciona pero para un aprendiz como yo, se me complica no tener una explicación para entender el proceso que se realizo.

Comment: @AlexGarzón Te complementé mi respuesta con unos links que te pueden ser utiles, en cuanto a esta respuesta, es efectivamente un toggle pero es algo raro implementar esa clase de logica, es innecesaria para algo tan simple como aplicar una condición, si es por no escribir las url, igual las estas introduciendo en un array asi que ponerlas en un par de variables no cuesta nada y asi te evitas la pequeña operación matematica jeje.